# How to add a button depending on number of child elements?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

So I have a bunch of spans contained within a div.  The functionality that I want is fairly simple but I'm not sure how I would execute.

```
<div>
    <span>1</span>
    <span>2</span>
    <span>3</span>
    <span>4</span>
    <span>5</span>
</div>
```

So lets say that I only want to display 3 spans only.  After 3 spans, there will be a button or another span with something like "..." which is clickable which I can then add an onClick or Hover event to display a selection of hidden spans that are not included in the view.  How would I achieve this?  Also doing this in a jsx file.

Comment: you can simply toggle based on click of ... buttons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should modify an array before render and create a flag to determine if the list is expanded (show all items) or not. Here is my example

```
const List = props => {
  const [expanded, setExpanded] = useState(false);
  const { items, limit = 3 } = props;

  const list = items.slice(0, expanded ? items.length : limit);

  return (
    <div>
      {list.map((item, index) => (
        <span key={index}>{item}</span>
      ))}
      <button onClick={()=>setExpanded(prev=>!prev)}>toggle</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

and usage

```
<List items={[1,2,3,4,5,6]} limit={4}/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `show` state variable to control where you want to show the rest of the content, `onClick` will set `show` to true:

```js
function MyComponent() {
    const [show, setShow] = useState(false)

    return (
    <div>
      <span>1</span>
      <span>2</span>
      <span>3</span>
      {
        show 
        ? <>
          <span>4</span>
          <span>5</span> 
        </>
        : <button onClick={() => setShow(!show)}>...</button>
      }
    </div>
  )
}
```

Is this what you want? https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-chandrasekhar-77fg3

Comment: Yes but only show the button if there are more than X amount of items otherwise it should be invisible.